# Is it possible to make lein include all clojure libraries in the user profile?

Tags: clojure

I know that I can depend on one by adding a line like

[org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "RELEASE"]

to ~/.lein/profiles.clj.  However, I'd like to depend on all all the org.clojure libraries (https://github.com/clojure) to make experimentation at the REPL more convenient.  Is there a way to do this besides just listing them all explicitly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible because lein needs to know what version of each library you want to use.

Fortunately leinengen when used with the refactor-nrepl middleware (which is included by default in the newest emacs/cider package) can hotload dependencies while your program is running which makes this somewhat more convenient

https://github.com/clojure-emacs/refactor-nrepl/blob/master/README.md#hotload-dependency

Comment: To clarify, I'm happy to use "RELEASE" as the version for each package.

Comment: I don't think a single version of all the projects exists, they are released independently

Comment: The string "RELEASE" always refers to the latest stable version of a package. It's not a placeholder.